# Querying and using the dark accent/theme color

Tags: windows-phone-7

If you look at the phones sms messages, it shows 2 colors in the chat dialogue. The one color is your chosen accent color and the other (your message) is a darker version of that accent color. I would like to find out what the resource name of that dark accent color is as I am writing my own chat application and trying to use the same colors the OS does.

Comment: Just to add to this, what I mean is that if my accent color is green, then I need to find the dark green color to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how you can get the dark accent color:

```
        Color accent = (Color)Resources["PhoneAccentColor"];
        Color darkAccent = Color.FromArgb(accent.A, (byte)(accent.R / 1.5), (byte)(accent.G / 1.5), (byte)(accent.B / 1.5));
```

Answer (score 0):

Check out this MSDN article: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552(v=vs.92).aspx. I'm not positive, but I think you're looking for `PhoneContrastForegroundBrush`.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked at that link but did not find the colour I am looking for.

Answer (score 0):

It is called `PhoneContrastBackgroundBrush`. It represents a color which helps in contrasting elements assigned the `PhoneBackgroundBrush`.

Comment: This color seems to return the opposite of the background color.